# Can I always sacrifice a permanent whenever I want, without anything telling me to do so?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can one sacrifice any permanent at any time for any reason, or is "permission" to sacrifice only granted by other cards?

Comment: I want to note that sacrifice isn't a special case. The rules say exactly what you can do and exactly when you can do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't spontaneously sacrifice a permanent. Even if you have a permanent with an ability of the form "whenever a creature dies" or "whenever a creature is sacrificed", you need to find some means of sacrificing it.

---

There's no rule forbidding it; there's simply no rule allowing it. CR 116 itemizes what actions you can perform. When you have priority<sup>[1]</sup>, you can do the following<sup>[2]</sup>:

- 116.1a Cast a spell.
- 116.1b Activate an activated ability.
- 116.1c Perform certain Special Actions.

  - 115.2a Play a land.
  - 115.2b Turn a face-down creature face up.
  - 115.2c Take an action an effect previously permitted you to take at a later time (usually to end a continuous effect or to stop a delayed triggered ability from triggering).
  - 115.2d Take an action a static ability allows you to take to ignore the effect of that static ability for a duration.
  - 115.2e Exile a card with Suspend.
  - 115.2f Role the Planar Die.
  - 115.2g Turn a face-down conspiracy card face up.
- 116.1d Activate a mana ability.

As you can see, sacrificing a Permanent is not an option (unless it's part of one of the above actions (e.g. The cost to activate an ability)).

---

1. There are other actions you can take (e.g. Drawing a card in your Draw Step), but they aren't actions you chose to do, so I won't bother listing them. They are itemized by CR 116.2.
2. Conditions may apply.

Answer (score 9):

You can only sacrifice a permanent when instructed to do so by some ability. Even if you had another ability such as "when a creature is sacrificed...", you would need something else to let you sacrifice a creature.